# ADT Eclipse/Android always builds/runs in debug mode ..how it will be fixed

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.

```
[2013-09-12 12:53:12 - Demo] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2013-09-12 12:53:12 - Demo] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\android-sdk-windows\android-sdk-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

I am getting this error...
How will be the problem solved?

Comment: I'm getting a `NullPointerException`. How can it be solved? Your question is as vague as this!

Answer (score 0):

go and check if adb is located here or not. If yes, then just click to execute it. This should work.

Comment: i have check it out but again an error occuring, that an host is forcing it to close the adt.